# Have logics with these exotic quantifiers been studied in the literature?

Tags: logic, reference-request

In standard first-order logic with equality, we can define what it means for there to be at least $n$ (as well as at most $n$) things that satisfy a property $P(x)$. However, we can't define an "exotic" quantifier like "there are an even natural number of $x$'s such that $P(x)$", or like "the number of $x$'s such that $P(x)$ is a natural number power of $4$", etc. Have logics with these kind of quantifiers been studied in the literature?

Comment: This sounds more like [predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) using [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality): "the set of things satisfying $P(x)$ has even cardinality" ${} \leftrightarrow {}$ "$|\{x : P(x)\}| \in 2\Bbb{Z}$".

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the feedback.  I therefore deleted my comment.

Comment: First order number theory, with $n$ a variable, already requires some fairly nasty gymnastics to state “there are at most $n$…,” doesn’t it? You essentially need something akin to encoding exponentiation in first order Peano postulated? I don’t see why such hoops aren’t possible for other counts.

Comment: @EricTowers These are examples of **generalized quantifiers**. In their most general form, a (unary) generalized quantifier $\mathsf{Q}$ is simply a function associating to each structure $\mathfrak{A}$ with underlying set $A$ a family of subsets of $A$. For example, "$\exists$" corresponds to the map $\mathfrak{A}\mapsto\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and "$\forall$" corresponds to the map $\mathfrak{A}\mapsto \{A\}$. See e.g. [the SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#GeneUnivExisQuan).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By standard compactness arguments, generalized quantifiers like these are **not** first-order expressible in general (although in a specific context like $\mathsf{PA}$ they may happen to add no additional expressive power).

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but some work trying to make Courcelle's Theorem into an equivalence uses second order logic with modular arithmetic size predicates on the second-order types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courcelle%27s_theorem#Modular_congruences

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, I’m specifically talking about first order number theory.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But the OP *isn't*, that's my point.